# Create a table with many rows without push in Knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'am trying to create a table with a 100 rows but I dont want to use push because then the page gets rendered for each push. The table should be empty at first but when I click a button the table will create all the rows. 
The problem here is that I dont se the rows when I click the button.
 But I can only set **self.row = ko.observableArray()** once?

**JS**

```
RowModel = function(numbers) {
    var self = this;
        self.numbers = numbers;
}

TableViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
        self.rows = null;

    self.createRows = function() {

        var arr = [];
        var numbers = [];
        for(var i=0; i < 100; i++){
            for(var p=0; p < 4; p++){
                numbers[p] = p;
            }
            arr[i] = new RowModel(numbers);
        }
        self.rows = ko.observableArray(arr);
    }
};
ko.applyBindings(new TableViewModel());
```

**HTML**

```
<button data-bind="click: createRows">Create</button>
<table>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: rows">
      <tr>
          <td data-bind="text: numbers[0]"></td
          <td data-bind="text: numbers[1]"></td>
          <td data-bind="text: numbers[2]"></td>
          <td data-bind="text: numbers[3]"></td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always create the observable up front, and set the data using a function call with the data e.g.

```
self.rows = ko.observable([]);
```

Then set the data (not as a push for each, as you correctly said) using:

```
self.rows(arr);
```

The full code is here in this fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/brianlmerritt/y0x0wwy5/

Comment: Ooo it was that easy :) Thank you